# How to bring an element to previous state after using jquery slideUp?

Tags: jquery, angular

I have the following html (message):

```
<div *ngIf="msgVisible == true" class="success_trip_msg" role="alert">                        
          <div>trip saved succesfully</div>
 </div>
```

After saving the data I have a jquery code to slide up the element after
few seconds which works fine as follow:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
        $('.success_trip_msg').slideUp();                                                                            
    }, 4000);
```

Now, the problem is that after the slide is finished, clicking save again
doesn't show the message (even though msgVisible = true"). I'm thinking that slideUp remove the element in a way that can't bring it back.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle.

Comment: fiddle is only for the jquery code

Comment: Use stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using

```
$('.success_trip_msg').show();
```

together with the angular condition:

```
this.msgVisible = true;
```